# How to make top links unclickable?

Tags: navigation, top-link-bar, site-settings, team-sites

Is there any way I can make the top links on the nav bar inactive? Basically I have created sites under the root such as

```
Company Info
HR
Team 1
Team 2....
```

and under each of those there are sub sites which show up in the drop down.

I want the top links

```
Company Info
HR
Team 1
Team 2....
```

to be inactive. So if a user clicks them they dont navigate to the site, can this be done? I would be ok with changing the link so it would just link back to the home page, but where would I change that?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. Use this:

```
$("body #s4-topheader2. ul li ul li.static > a").each(function(index) {

if(index!=2)
{

    $(this).attr("href","javascript:void(0);");
}

});
```

Cheers !

Comment: you are the man! Thank you! thats exactly what I needed.

Comment: Pleasure to be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

I tested this line of jQuery against a SP2010 page running the v4.master

```
$().ready(function(){
 $(".menu-horizontal").find("a").removeAttr("href");
});
```

Put this right on the master page, or hook it up to a CustomAction to load this all over the site.

Be aware that certain features in SharePoint(like Publishing Infrastructure, for example) alter the DOM a little so you may have to F12 this if it doesn't work at first.

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me...I added this to my master page <head> 

    `<script type="text/javascript">  
      $().ready(function(){  
 $(".menu-horizontal").find("a").removeAttr("href");  
  });  
 </script>`  
I am using the Publishing Infrastructure, is that the issue?

Comment: I forgot to mention, I tried replacing .menu-horizontal with a number of different tags including .s4-tn and I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: Is jquery included? If it isn't then the script won't do anything.

Comment: Thanks! it works! however its not quite what I need, that basically disables the links that show up in the drop down under the main headings, is there a way to only disable the top links and not the ones in the dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

I was having same requirement. and this works for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $("body #s4-topheader2. ul li ul li a").attr("href","javascript:void(0);");
});
```

May be it helps you.

Don't forget to include JQuery in your master page.

Comment: Thanks! it works! however its not quite what I need, that basically disables the links that show up in the drop down under the main headings, is there a way to only disable the top links and not the ones in the dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will helps you to get your requirements:

```
$("body #s4-topheader2. ul li ul li.static > a").attr("href","javascript:void(0);");
```

Comment: awesome! thank you! that works perfectly, is there any way to activate just the first link? For example one of the web apps we have has a home link, can I have just that link active and not the rest?

Answer (score 0):

Would putting the following in the header work?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("body #TopNavigationMenuV4. ul li ul li.static > a").each(function(index) {
if(index!=2) {
$(this).attr("href","javascript:void(0);");
}
});
</script>
```

I couldn't get this working at all...

Comment: where do you put this code, in a script web part on the page?